# Why does the limit when h=0 mean that c=2pi*r?

Tags: calculus

The author is proving the formula for a circumference of a circle by taking the derivative of the formula for a circle's area- in the below image, c represents the circumference of a circle in general, C represents the circumference of a circle whose radius is h units larger than the radius of c, and pi*(2r+h) is a simplified version of the newton quotient. When taking the limit as h approaches 0, I am confused as to how we conclude that c=2*(pi)r in this inequality. I understand that when h approaches zero, C approaches c, but wouldn't setting c equivalent to 2*(pi)*r violate the fact that c is supposed to be less than this quantity
[image]

thanks

Comment: The author has specifically used the $\lim_{h \to 0} \dots$ by stating _"h approach $0$"_, instead of directly substituting $h = 0$. This most likely suggests the non-existence of the function at $h = 0$ (discontinuous/asymptotic). Hence, the domain should be $c < \pi (2r + h) \dots$ rather than $c \le \pi (2r + h) \dots$, since only via the limit, it exists at $h = 0$.

Answer (score 1):

To extend on my comment, if circumference is the derivative of the area of a circle, then it holds the following;

If $A(r) = \pi r^2$, then by definition the derivative is $$A'(r) = \lim_{h \to 0}{\frac{A(r + h) - A(r)}{r + h - r}} = \lim_{h \to 0}{\frac{\pi(r + h)^2 - \pi r^2}{h}} = \lim_{h \to 0}{\frac{\pi r^2+2\pi rh + \pi h^2 - \pi r^2}{h}} = \lim_{h \to 0}{\frac{\pi \require{\enclose }\enclose{updiagonalstrike}{h} (2r + h)}{\require{\enclose }\enclose{updiagonalstrike}{h}}} =  \lim_{h \to 0}{\pi (2r + h)}$$

Now, observe how we divided by $h$. This means in our new domain $h ≠ 0$ (that is, $c < \pi(2r + h)$).

However, the limit still exists at $h = 0$ (or as $h$ becomes
infinitesimally small to approach the true derivate). Hence, $$\lim_{h \to 0}{\pi (2r + h)} = 2\pi r = c$$

Comment: thanks, this helps me see how this is not contradictory to the domain. However, I am still a little confused about the actual logic of concluding c is equivalent to 2(pi)c given that C (circumference of bigger circle) is approaching c, and 2*pi*c is between these. Is the logic similar to the squeeze theorem?

Comment: @God Yes, the logic is similar to the squeeze theorem but not its definition. Theoretically, you could consider $c$ the lower bound as in the squeeze theorem with $h > 0$ always and $C$ the upperbound that is dependent on the $\max(h)$. Then, as $h \to 0 \implies C \to c$. Lastly, by "logic" of squeeze theorem, we must have $\pi(2r + h) = c$ as $h \to 0$ as $c < \pi(2r + h) < C$ consistently.

Comment: I was just thinking of something- we know that c approaches 2(pi)r, but if we don't assume that circumference is derivative of area, how can we show it is equal to this when h=0, not just that its limit is this? As circumference being  derivative of area was not assumed here, it was rather supposed to be shown.

Comment: Once you use the format _"$h$ approaches $0$"_, you are assuming limits and hence calculus comes into play. I am afraid to my knowledge, I do not know another relation between circumference and area, without calculus. However, if you are interested there are geometric interpretations of circumference, but they do not rely on the area.